# foreign key in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i am beginner in mysql and have a simple question.
i have three tables in my schema(bookshop). i want to have a relationship between them.
my tables: books(book_id,book_name,book_entity),customer(customer_id,customer_name),orders(book_id,customer_id,quantity).
i set the foreign key in orders table as following:

**foreign key names(book_id and customer_id ) ,             reference table(
                       'bookshop','books'
                  'bookshop','customer')**

at first i fill the books table,but when i am trying to insert data in customer table i have following error:

```
  ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bookshop`.`customer`, CONSTRAINT `customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `order` (`customer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL Statement:

INSERT INTO `bookshop`.`customer` (`customer_id`, `customer_name`, `customer_address`) VALUES (2, 'helen', 'newyork')
```

what shall i do?

my codes:

---

```
-- Table `bookshop`.`books`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookshop`.`books` (

  `book_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `book_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  `book_price` DECIMAL NOT NULL ,

  `book_entity` INT NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;





-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `bookshop`.`customer`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookshop`.`customer` (

  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `customer_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  `customer_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;





-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `bookshop`.`orders`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookshop`.`orders` (

  `book_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL ,

  `quantity` INT NOT NULL ,

  INDEX `book_id` (`book_id` ASC) ,

  INDEX `customer_id` (`customer_id` ASC) ,

  CONSTRAINT `book_id`

    FOREIGN KEY (`book_id` )

    REFERENCES `bookshop`.`books` (`book_id` )

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `customer_id`

    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id` )

    REFERENCES `bookshop`.`customer` (`customer_id` )

    ON DELETE RESTRICT

    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: this is because you don't have corresponding `customer_id` in main table where you have `customer_id` as primary key.

Comment: __foreign key names reference table book_id 'bookshop','books' customer_id 'bookshop','customer'__ doesn't make much sense. Re-write how have you defined goreign keys.

Comment: i just want to have a relationship between my tables. the foreign keys: customer_id and book_id in my orders table.(they are primary too)

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key statement seems to be off, please provide the statement you used to create the foreign key.

However, it seems you created a foreign key that only allows you to insert a customer if a order to the customer exists.
You probably want to do it the other way around.

Comment: i use workbench and in data modeling i set the foreign keys of orders table.

Comment: The code you provided looks ok, I guess you might still have other foreign keys around from playing around or something? You might want to double check if there are no other constraints defined, especially the one on customer.customer_id that the error states

Comment: thank you Tim, my problem solved. i reset the primary keys in my orders table. i am beginner and have crazy mistake in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error occurs is because of [integrity constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity).
The problem is that you are trying to add a dataset with a reference that is invalid. Mostly this is because the foreign key points to a nonexistent Primary key. In your case this is probably because you are adding a customer and the customer somehow has a reference that is invalid.
You probably have the relations mixed up.
Without more information on your relations it's just guessing.